# Cannot seem to be able to debug MySQL error “#1064

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am sure this question has been asked far to many times.
If anyone could give it a look would be be great

> I get   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'REFERENCES interests(interests_id))' while creating category_interests and event_attendees table  using interests.interest_id as reference to define foreign keys.

I cannot seem to find out a reason for it.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP table IF EXISTS categories;
CREATE table categories(
  category_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  category_name VARCHAR(40),
  category_desc TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_categories PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);

DROP table IF EXISTS interests;
CREATE table interests(
  interest_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  interest_name varchar(40),

  CONSTRAINT pk_interests PRIMARY KEY (interest_id)
);


-- ERROR - query does not run 
DROP table IF EXISTS category_interests;
CREATE table category_interests(
  interest_id int,
  category_id int,
  CONSTRAINT fk_interests FOREIGN KEY interest_id REFERENCES interests(interest_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_categories FOREIGN KEY category_id REFERENCES categories(category_id)
);

-- ERROR - query does not run
DROP table IF EXISTS event_atendees;
CREATE table event_atendees(
     attendee_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    interest_id int,
    lat double,
    lon double,
    name varchar(115),
    dob date,
    gender CHAR(1),

  CONSTRAINT pk_event_atendees PRIMARY KEY (attendee_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_intrests_ea FOREIGN KEY interests_id REFERENCES `interests`(interests_id)
);

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faults I've found:

1. You forgot to enclose the foreign key column by `()`. It should be
   `CONSTRAINT fk_interests FOREIGN KEY (interest_id) REFERENCES interests(interest_id)`. It should not be `CONSTRAINT fk_interests FOREIGN KEY interest_id....` (without parentheses)
2. Somewhere you used `interests_id`. But you should have used
   `interest_id`.

---

Try this:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP table IF EXISTS categories;
CREATE table categories(
  category_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  category_name VARCHAR(40),
  category_desc TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_categories PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
);

DROP table IF EXISTS interests;
CREATE table interests(
  interest_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  interest_name varchar(40),

  CONSTRAINT pk_interests PRIMARY KEY (interest_id)
);


-- ERROR - query does not run 
DROP table IF EXISTS category_interests;
CREATE table category_interests(
  interest_id int,
  category_id int,
  CONSTRAINT fk_interests FOREIGN KEY (interest_id) REFERENCES interests(interest_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_categories FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(category_id)
);

-- ERROR - query does not run
DROP table IF EXISTS event_atendees;
CREATE table event_atendees(
     attendee_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    interest_id int,
    lat double,
    lon double,
    name varchar(115),
    dob date,
    gender CHAR(1),

  CONSTRAINT pk_event_atendees PRIMARY KEY (attendee_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_intrests_ea FOREIGN KEY (interest_id) REFERENCES `interests`(interest_id)
);

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6c965/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: I've already mentioned the changes I made. Here's a working demo of your schema. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6c965/2/0. @NishonTandukar

Comment: I have fixed the faults that were identified
now  i get `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint `
 while i try to create **event_atendess** table

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `event_atendees`? Please check the working demo. It successfully executes all the queries.

Comment: Yes, i removed my first comment the moment i saw you mentioned the faults

Comment: I was getting `#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint` even after copy pasting the queries you provided
but i tried a few times and **it worked**

Comment: May be typo in the table name `event_atendess` which is supposed to be `event_atendees`.